# How can you reduce(...) the entries of a JavaScript Map object without expanding to a list?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, functional-programming

It seems there's no good standard library way of doing something like this?

```js
let thismap = new Map([[1,2],[2,3]])
console.log(thismap.entries().reduce((prev, [a,b])=>prev + a * b, 0))
```

`Uncaught TypeError: thismap.entries(...).reduce is not a function`

I assume this is due to the entries() function returning an iterator? I don't want to `Array.from(thismap.entries()).reduce(...)`, as that would unnecessarily build the array in memory. It feels like I'm missing something, but I also don't want to reimplement something that should be in the standard library.

I suppose if I was using an object instead (not a satisfactory solution here for other reasons), the entries() would essentially be an array expansion instead of an iterator (although I suppose it could be implemented with memory efficiency in mind). But still, I'd want to know how to reduce an iterator

Comment: Not very functional, but a `for...of` loop can consume an iterator directly.

Comment: JavaScript iterators don't have the very convenient array methods. And most of the examples you'll find involve expanding the iterator into an array. What you could do though is implement your own set of helper functions to emulate the array methods on iterators and abstract away the `for-of` loops. There are also [third-party libraries](https://fitzgen.github.io/wu.js) available that do the same.

Comment: Note that `Array.from(thismap.entries())` could just be shortened to `Array.from(thismap)`, there is no reason to call `entries()`.

Comment: `Array.from(thismap).reduce(...)` will probably be my preferred resolution to this for the time being, but it seems odd you can't reduce an iterator if you can reduce an array, and just wanted to make sure I wasn't mistaken! Thanks all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I also don't want to reimplement something that should be in the standard library.

It really should indeed. There's a proposal to add it: [*Iterator Helpers*](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers). While waiting for it, you can already use [the polyfill](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#iterator-helpers) which will make your original code work :-)

Comment: Glad to know there's an active proposal! Does "Stage 2 of The TC39 Process" give any ballpark (wildly inaccurate is acceptable) of the amount of time until it's implemented in chrome if accepted?

Comment: @brubsby Not really, unfortunately. Some proposals sit idle for years until finally accepted, others progress much faster.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `for of` loop and handle the summing manually. This uses the iterator without creating a temporary array. Note that here we don't even have to call `entries` manually because `Map.prototype[Symbol.iterator] === Map.prototype.entries`.

```js
const map = new Map([[1, 2], [2, 3]])

let sum = 0
for (const [a, b] of map) sum += a * b

console.log(sum)
```

You can of course also factor this out into a utility function in case you need it more often. Here I created a function `lazyReduce` that works like `Array.prototype.reduce` but operates on iterables of any kind:

```js
function lazyReduce (originalIterable, callback, initialValue) {
  let i = 0
  let accumulator = initialValue
  let iterable = originalIterable
  
  // This part exists to implement the behavior of reduce without initial value
  // in the same way Array.prototype.reduce does it
  if (arguments.length < 3) {
    iterable = iterable[Symbol.iterator]()
    const { value, done } = iterable.next()
    if (done) throw new TypeError('Reduce of empty iterable with no initial value')
    accumulator = value
    i++
  }
  
  for (const element of iterable) {
    accumulator = callback(accumulator, element, i++, originalIterable)
  }
  
  return accumulator
}

const map = new Map([[1, 2], [2, 3]])

console.log(lazyReduce(map, (prev, [a, b]) => prev + a * b, 0))
```

If you wanted, you could extend the prototypes of `Map`, `Set`, etc., i.e. `Map.prototype.reduce = function (...args) { return lazyReduce(this, ...args) }`. (Note: Some other things that return iterators would be harder to extend, but still possible. For example `RegExpStringIterator` which doesn't exist as global variable, but you can still do `Object.getPrototypeOf(''.matchAll(/./g)).reduce = ...`. Similar ideas would work for `Generator`.)

Comment: I suppose this fulfills the "without expanding to a list", but a functional solution would be preferable. Especially if js already implements `Map.forEach(...)`, and objects have `Object.entries({"1":2, "2":3}).reduce(...)`

Comment: @brubsby There is no such solution existing by default, but I added my own now. See my edit.